# How to load external content and apply css via js hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading wikipedia on a modal, once it is loaded i want to change the background color of any element i mouse hover. The code below does apply a hover function but it doesn't work.

> Click the button wikipedia, then click on a result,, once the page is
>   loaded hover any element and its background should change as per the
>   code below - [JSFiddle playground](https://jsfiddle.net/kgyc8to4/85/)

```
    $("#wiki").one('click', function(e) {
        var articleName = $(this).data('subject');
        $.getJSON("https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=?", {
            srsearch: articleName,
            action: "query",
            list: "search",
            format: "json"
        }, function(data) {
            $("#results ul").empty();
            $("#results ul").append("<h3>Results for <b>" + articleName + "</b></h3>").text();
            $.each(data.query.search, function(i, item) {
                $("#results").append("<div class='list-group'><a class='list-group-item' href='https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + encodeURIComponent(item.title.replace(" ", "_")) + "' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.bs-example-modal-lg'><h4>" + item.title.replace(" ", "_") + "</h4><p class='list-group-item-text'>" + item.snippet + "</p></a></div>");
                $("#results div a").attr("href", "#");
            });
            $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
                $.getJSON("https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&callback=?", {
                    page: $(e.relatedTarget).find('h4').text(), 
                    prop:"text"
                }, function(data) {
                    var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
                    var blurb = $('<div></div>').html(markup);
                    blurb.find('a').each(function() { 
                        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); 
                    });
                    blurb.find(".mw-editsection, #toc, .noprint, .thumb, img").remove();
                    $(".modal-header .modal-title").html(articleName);
                    $(".modal-header .modal-title").promise().done(function(){
                        $(".modal-title").css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0});
                    });
                    $(".modal-body").html($(blurb));
                    $(".modal-body").promise().done(function(){
                        $(".modal-content").html(data.parse.text['*']);
                        saveWiki();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
    function saveWiki() {
      $('.modal-body').find().children().on("mouseover", function() {
        $("this").css("background-color", "yellow");
      });
    };
```

Comment: your fiddle has not the same code as shown here there is no `modal-body`  (thumbs down)

Comment: @caramba sorry updated, it was part of a more complex code and i was just checking the fiddle while i posted the question. Help still required tho, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the function at the bottom of the code:

```
function saveWiki() {
  $(".modal-content *").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
  }).mouseout(function(){
     $(this).css("background-color", "white");
  });
};
```